# Meteor Error: No such function: only in production mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

My App is running perfectly in debug mode but when I run it in production mode I get:

> Error: No such function: canAddMore

Here is the JS code I have:

```
Template.fbRegister.helpers({
    jobCount: function() {
        return Session.get("jobCount");
    },

    eduCount: function() {
        return Session.get("eduCount");
    },

    moreThanOneJob: function() {
        return Session.get('jobCount').length > 1
    },

    moreThanOneEdu: function() {
        return Session.get('eduCount').length > 1
    },

    canAddMore: function(count) {
        console.log(count)
        return count.length <= 2
    },
});
```

And here is the HTML code:

```
{{#if canAddMore jobCount}}<a class="normal-link add-job">+ Add another Job</a>{{/if}}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably breaks in production, due to several **missing semicolons**. When deploying your Meteor application, your code will be **minified**. During this process, blank lines will be removed and therefore it would be no longer possible to distinguish when a statement ends.

Please try:

```
Template.fbRegister.helpers({
    jobCount: function () {
        return Session.get("jobCount");
    },
    eduCount: function () {
        return Session.get("eduCount");
    },
    moreThanOneJob: function () {
        return Session.get('jobCount').length > 1;
    },
    moreThanOneEdu: function () {
        return Session.get('eduCount').length > 1;
    },
    canAddMore: function (count) {
        console.log(count);
        return count.length <= 2;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that Matthias. Someone suggested that earlier and I went through all my JS files to fix all the semicolons I missed. It didn't do the trick. So I restarted the App from scratch running it in production mode at all times and fixing the problems as they show up. So far so good.